# How to trigger Clockwork task at the beginning of the month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clockwork

I would like to run task every beginning of the month. E.g.:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00 // January has just started
2017-02-01 00:00:00 // February has just started ...
...
```

How to do this using clockwork?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
every(1.day, 'myjob', at: '00:00', :if => lambda { |t| t.day == 1 }) do ... end
```